# how to read compiler flags from a file

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, clang

Is it possible to configure clang to read the compiler flags from a file. Is there any flag like:

```
 clang++ test.cpp -flags=flags-file
```

Such that `clang` reads the compiler flags from `flags-file`.

Comment: Have you considered using [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)?

Comment: Assuming you are using a unix-style shell: ``clang++ test.cpp `cat flags-file` `` [or something along those lines] - but using `make` seems like a much better idea...

Comment: Even I would have preferred `make` but this is not my decision. The idea is to ban some of the warnings in the software by specifying some warnings as error. And the list of warnings will be supplied by 'someone else'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is support for reading commands from a file in clang as well as in gcc. The usage is something like:

```
clang++ test.cpp @file
```

The compiler will read the command line flags from `file`.

I could find a link for gcc. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/gcc.1.html

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved with the command:

```
clang++ test.cpp -flags=`cat flags-file`
```

as FDinoff suggested in the comments, make seems like the tool for the job though.